Unable to download the libntlm package
I execute these scripts for building the Ubuntu 22.04 image through the DevOps pipeline.
sudo apt update --fix-missing

echo deb https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu jammy main >> /etc/apt/sources.list

echo deb http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy main universe multiverse restricted >> /etc/apt/sources.list

echo deb http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates main multiverse universe restricted >> /etc/apt/sources.list

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt clean && sudo apt autoclean

sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 4f4ea0aae5267a6c

sudo apt-get install libntlm0

But when the pipeline runs I am getting this error and it is failing.
Get:5 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu jammy InRelease [23.9 kB]
azure-arm.ubuntu2204lts: Err:5 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu jammy InRelease
azure-arm.ubuntu2204lts:   The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 4F4EA0AAE5267A6C


W: GPG error: https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu jammy InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 4F4EA0AAE5267A6C
==> azure-arm.ubuntu2204lts: E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu jammy InRelease' is not signed.


Err:1 http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe amd64 libntlm0 amd64 1.6-4
    azure-arm.ubuntu2204lts:   404  Not Found [IP: 20.53.66.23 80]
==> azure-arm.ubuntu2204lts: E: Failed to fetch http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/libn/libntlm/libntlm0_1.6-4_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 20.53.66.23 80]
==> azure-arm.ubuntu2204lts: E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?


This appears to be a network issue. Have you tried switching to a different server in your software sources settings?

Looks like https://azure.archive.ubuntu.com is not reachable. As a workaround, you can download libntml binary and install it with the following commands:
curl -O http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/libn/libntlm/libntlm0_1.6-4_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libntlm0_1.6-4_amd64.deb

